Advanced Access for Inactive Play Store App
I'm seeking some clarification regarding the Facebook Login advanced access requirement for my Android app.
Current Situation:
in my Android app.
My app is currently not active on the Play Store.
To proceed with development, I need to enable advanced access for the public_profile, email permission.
Question:
Is it possible to enable advanced access for a non-active Play Store app?
If so, what steps should I take to achieve this?
Facebook Screenshot
I appreciate any insights or guidance the community can offer.
Thanks,
I am unable to find the solution for this

Why would you need advanced access, to be able to proceed with your development? Standard access allows your app to request permissions from all users with a role in the app.

Hi @CBrore thank you for reply
i did attach the screenshot please check , now  FB login require the "Advance Access"
